# SQL CASE WHEN ...AND

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, case

Is there a way to write a SQL query like this:

```
CASE WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2013 AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) = 3         
        THEN @AdjStartYear = '2012/07/01' AND @AdjEndYear = '2012/12/31'
```

Basically, I want 2 things to happen after the CASE statement is evaluated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you have to make 2 case statements

```
select @AdjStartYear = CASE WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2013 AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) = 3
                            THEN  '2012/07/01' 
                       END,
       @AdjEndYear = CASE WHEN DATEPART(yy,@year_end) = 2013 AND DATEPART(mm,@year_end) = 3
                          THEN  '2012/12/31' 
                     END
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it without the `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT @AdjStartYear = '2012/07/01', @AdjEndYear = '2012/12/31'
WHERE DATEPART(year, @year_end) = 2013 AND DATEPART(month, @year_end) = 3
```

This only performs the operation if the `WHERE` criteria is met. [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/35676)