# Case statement with more than one condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to fetch records from a table based on days visited. How can I achieve this by correcting the query below? It has syntax error(s). I know the syntax is incorrect, but it will give you an idea on what I want to achieve.

```
DECLARE @PatientByDate INT
 SET @PatientByDate  = 30
    SELECT * FROM Visits
     WHERE
    CASE  
           WHEN(@PatientByDate = 90) then DaysVisited > 90
           WHEN(@PatientByDate = 60) then DaysVisited >= 60 AND DaysVisited < 90
           WHEN(@PatientByDate = 30) then DaysVisited >= 30 AND DaysVisited < 60
           WHEN(@PatientByDate = 25) then DaysVisited < 30
           WHEN(@PatientByDate = 0) then -500 AND <= 5000000
      END
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254164/sql-case-when-and

Comment: `CASE` is **not** a statement - it's an **expression** (that can return one of various possible values). You **cannot**  return "code blocks" or conditions from a `CASE` - only a single, atomic value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it directly combining predicates with `or`:

```
SELECT * FROM Visits
WHERE
    (@PatientByDate = 90 and DaysVisited > 90) or
    (@PatientByDate = 60 and DaysVisited >= 60 and DaysVisited < 90) or
    (@PatientByDate = 30 and DaysVisited >= 30 and DaysVisited < 60) or
    (@PatientByDate = 25 and DaysVisited < 30) or
    (@PatientByDate in(0, -500))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to move them all to the *When* clause and match it to the returned value (=1):

```
DECLARE @PatientByDate INT
SET @PatientByDate  = 30
SELECT * FROM Visits
WHERE 1 = CASE  
    WHEN(@PatientByDate = 90) AND DaysVisited > 90 then 1 
    WHEN(@PatientByDate = 60) AND DaysVisited >= 60 AND DaysVisited < 90 then 1 
    WHEN(@PatientByDate = 30) AND DaysVisited >= 30 AND DaysVisited < 60 then 1 
    WHEN(@PatientByDate = 25) AND DaysVisited < 30 then 1 
    WHEN(@PatientByDate = 0) AND -500 AND <= 5000000 then 1 
END
```

Or simply do:

```
DECLARE @PatientByDate INT
SET @PatientByDate  = 30
SELECT * FROM Visits
WHERE 
    ((@PatientByDate = 90) AND DaysVisited > 90) OR 
    ((@PatientByDate = 60) AND DaysVisited >= 60 AND DaysVisited < 90) OR 
    ((@PatientByDate = 30) AND DaysVisited >= 30 AND DaysVisited < 60) OR
    ((@PatientByDate = 25) AND DaysVisited < 30) OR
    ((@PatientByDate = 0) AND -500 AND <= 5000000)
```